# Identifying changes in a sequence of data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame.

| sensor_id | u_code | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:41 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:42 |
| abcd | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:43 |
| abcd | 6 | 2022-06-17 16:22:44 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:45 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:46 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:47 |
| abcd | 8 | 2022-06-17 16:22:48 |
| efgh | 4 | 2022-06-17 16:22:49 |
| efgh | 4 | 2022-06-17 16:22:50 |
| efgh | 2 | 2022-06-17 16:22:51 |
| efgh | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:52 |
| efgh | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:53 |
| efgh | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:54 |
| efgh | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:55 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:22:56 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:22:57 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:22:58 |
| efgh | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:59 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:23:00 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:23:01 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:23:02 |
| efgh | 6 | 2022-06-17 16:23:03 |

What I need is that, when ever the u_code is 1, 2 or 3; I want to compare it against the u_code other than itself immediately before it and after it. If the u_code before and after are same, I want to ignore them and only show the dataframe where the u_code before and after a sequence of 1, 2 or 3 are different. Also, I want a check if the sensor ID is same when the comparison is done.

Below is my expected output.

| sensor_id | u_code | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 6 | 2022-06-17 16:22:44 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:45 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:46 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:47 |
| abcd | 8 | 2022-06-17 16:22:48 |
| efgh | 4 | 2022-06-17 16:22:50 |
| efgh | 2 | 2022-06-17 16:22:51 |
| efgh | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:52 |
| efgh | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:59 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:23:00 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:23:01 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:23:02 |
| efgh | 6 | 2022-06-17 16:23:03 |

My desired output is marked in brown in the picture below.

To explain with examples

- in the first green marked zone, the sensor_id is abcd and u_code before 1 is 5 and after 1 is also 5. So we can filter this out as the u_code has not changed after the sequence of 1.
- in the next area marked in brown, we have sensor_id abcd and a u_code 1 preceded by u_code 6. The u_code after 1 is again 1 followed by another 1. We keep looking for a u_code other than 1 with same sensor_id and finally reach 8. As 8 is different to the u_code 6 which was prior to the sequence of 1's , we want to keep this part of the data frame.

Similar checks are needed for u_codes 2 and 3 also.

[image]

Comment: then why to do you keep `2022-06-17 16:22:46` or `2022-06-17 16:23:01`? There is the same value before and after. Also do you need to consider per sensor_id?

Comment: I need to know at which all time stamps the sequence failed due to different u_code before and after the sequence. I want also a check if the sensor_id is same when comparing a sequence. Thanks for pointing out. I have added that to the question.

Comment: You didn't really answer the first question, check the answer below and see if this is what you want ;)

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. I hope this clarifies the question for you. Your code doesn't give me the desired output yet.

Comment: [pandas.DataFrame.diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use:

```
m1 = df['u_code'].isin([1,2,3])
g  = df.groupby('sensor_id')['u_code']
# drop values where previous == next, except if also equal to self
m2 = g.shift().ne(g.shift(-1)) | g.shift().eq(df['u_code'])
out = df[m2.rolling(3, center=True).min().fillna(0).astype(bool)]
```

output:

```
   sensor_id  u_code                   ts
3       abcd       6  2022-06-17 16:22:44
4       abcd       1  2022-06-17 16:22:45
5       abcd       1  2022-06-17 16:22:46
6       abcd       1  2022-06-17 16:22:47
7       abcd       8  2022-06-17 16:22:48
8       efgh       4  2022-06-17 16:22:49
9       efgh       4  2022-06-17 16:22:50
10      efgh       2  2022-06-17 16:22:51
11      efgh       5  2022-06-17 16:22:52
12      efgh       5  2022-06-17 16:22:53
13      efgh       5  2022-06-17 16:22:54
14      efgh       5  2022-06-17 16:22:55
15      efgh       3  2022-06-17 16:22:56
16      efgh       3  2022-06-17 16:22:57
20      efgh       3  2022-06-17 16:23:01
21      efgh       3  2022-06-17 16:23:02
```

Comment: I have updated the question with examples.

Comment: What does IIUC means? I always see you answer it like that

Comment: @INGl0R1AM0R1 "*If I Understand Correctly*", yes I use it too much, mostly when I write from my phone ;)

Comment: @mozway, maybe change the last line to

out = df[m2.rolling(3, center=True).min().bfill().ffill().astype(bool)]

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that produces what you are looking for:

```py
u_code = df['u_code'].values
# The u_codes of interest that should be in the middle
middle_codes = {1, 2, 3}
start_code = middle_code = None
start_idx = end_idx = None
keep_idxs = []
for i, u_code in enumerate(u_code):
    if middle_code is not None:
        if u_code != middle_code:
            if u_code != start_code:
                keep_idxs.extend(range(start_idx, i + 1))
            start_idx = middle_code = None
    if middle_code is None:
        if u_code in middle_codes:
            # Sequence validation
            if start_idx is None or start_idx == i:
                raise ValueError('Invalid sequence of u_codes (start code is a middle_code or the first element of the sequence is a middle_code)')
            else:
                middle_code = u_code
        else:
            start_idx = i
            start_code = u_code
# Take unique indices
print(df.iloc[sorted(set(keep_idxs))])
```

Output:

```
   sensor_id  u_code                   ts
3       abcd       6  2022-06-17 16:22:44
4       abcd       1  2022-06-17 16:22:45
5       abcd       1  2022-06-17 16:22:46
6       abcd       1  2022-06-17 16:22:47
7       abcd       8  2022-06-17 16:22:48
9       efgh       4  2022-06-17 16:22:50
10      efgh       2  2022-06-17 16:22:51
11      efgh       5  2022-06-17 16:22:52
18      efgh       5  2022-06-17 16:22:59
19      efgh       3  2022-06-17 16:23:00
20      efgh       3  2022-06-17 16:23:01
21      efgh       3  2022-06-17 16:23:02
22      efgh       6  2022-06-17 16:23:03
```

Answer (score 0):

A purely pandas solution is possible:
The approach is to fill the u_code > 3, up and down in a working column. When the codes are equal for a u_code = 1,2, or 3 we have to remove it and its near neighbours.

```
df = pd.read_csv("pandasData\Data05.csv", sep='\t')
cols = df.columns
df["u_code_p"] = df["u_code"].apply(lambda x: x if x > 3 else None).ffill() 
df["u_code_n"] = df["u_code"].apply(lambda x: x if x > 3 else None).bfill() 
df["rm"] = (df["u_code_p"] == df["u_code_n"]) & df["u_code"].isin([1,2,3])
df["up"] = df["rm"].shift( 1, fill_value=False)
df["dn"] = df["rm"].shift(-1, fill_value=False)
df[~df[["up","dn","rm"]].any(axis=1)][cols]
```

Giving the required result:

[image]

The code assumes that the sensor_ids are contiguous. If this is not the case, the df needs to be sorted on this field.

Comment: Index 8, 12, 13 should no be present and Index 18 should?

Comment: @Corralien, index 8 is not present in the sample output, however, there is no rule I can see that excludes it.

Comment: The expected output is the brown rows in the image. check the rule.

Answer (score 0):

As you have rows that can belong to 2 groups (index 18, 2022-06-17 16:22:59), you have to duplicate this rows first. Now you can create some boolean mask to create groups of values (5, 3, 3, 3, 6) and check if the ends are different:

```
def find_groups(uc):
    # 1st: duplicates some rows to create groups (like index 18)
    rpt = (uc.rolling(3, center=True, min_periods=3)
             .apply(lambda x: x.le(3).eq([True, False, True]).all())
             .fillna(0).add(1))
    uc1 = uc.reindex(uc.index.repeat(rpt))

    # 2nd: create groups and check the end values
    m0 = uc1 <= 3
    m1 = (uc1 > 3) & m0.shift(-1)
    m2 = (uc1 > 3) & m0.shift(1)
    idx = (uc1.groupby((m1|m2.shift()).cumsum().where(m0|m1|m2))
              .transform(lambda x: x.iloc[0] != x.iloc[-1])
              .loc[lambda x: x]).index

    # 3rd: return the boolean mask for the sensor_id              
    return pd.Series(uc.index.isin(idx), index=uc.index)

out = df[df.groupby('sensor_id')['u_code'].apply(find_groups)]
```

Output:

| sensor_id | u_code | ts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | 6 | 2022-06-17 16:22:44 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:45 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:46 |
| abcd | 1 | 2022-06-17 16:22:47 |
| abcd | 8 | 2022-06-17 16:22:48 |
| efgh | 4 | 2022-06-17 16:22:50 |
| efgh | 2 | 2022-06-17 16:22:51 |
| efgh | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:52 |
| efgh | 5 | 2022-06-17 16:22:59 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:23:00 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:23:01 |
| efgh | 3 | 2022-06-17 16:23:02 |
| efgh | 6 | 2022-06-17 16:23:03 |

Comment: @aj7amigo Did you have time to test the solutions?